# How to solve type mismatch (Run Error 13) for Date in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code in my excel. I have employees date of birth on Row F. Now, using VBA, I want phrase called "Happy Birthday" on column G for those employees who have birthdays. My table starts from row 6 to row 50. I wrote the following code but it always gives error in Month(Range("f" & y)). The month function gives me error. If, for example, I only write Range("f" & y), it will work fine. This means the Date of birth on column F isn't being recognized as DATE in my VBA (they are in date format in excel). There is a mismatch for sure. Can someone please help me how to fix this issue (using for next function as shown below)?>

```
Sheets("Employees").Select
For y = 6 To 50
If Month(VBA.Date) = Month(Range("f" & y)) Then
Range("g" & y).Value = "HBD"
Else
Range("g" & y).Value = "No hbd"
End If
Next y
```

Note: A). I am looking at the month of date of birth only for wishing happy birthday and I am not looking at day. B). I want message called HBD or NO HBD to be posted on column G for each employee based on their DOB given on Column F .

Comment: You could use a formula:  `=IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(F2),DAY(F2))=TODAY(),"Happy Birthday","")`

Comment: That wouldn't work. The cell value should keep changing from F6 to F7 to F8 to F50 for the rest of the employees as we are posting happy birthday message for each employee in column G. (Also, I am looking at month of date of birth only for wishing happy birthday and I am not looking at day).

Comment: I've just tried your code here, and it worked for me. No errors... I simply put dates (dd/mm in my case) in colum F, and for the lines it was 4 as a month it worked as expected...

Comment: If the `Month`-function fails, probably you don't have a date in the cell. Note that the cell format doesn't say anything about the content - if you put "ABC" in a cell that is formatted as date, it's still not a date. And even a string "01/04/2021" is not necessarily a date - it still can be a string. Check in the debugger what the content of the cell is when you get the runtime error. That said, using a formula as @DarrenBartrup-Cook suggest is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

With a formula I think you should be able to do it with `=IF(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH(F6),"HBD","No HBD")`.

For a VBA solution use:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees")
        For y = 6 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
            If Month(Date) = Month(.Cells(y, 6)) Then
                .Cells(y, 7) = "HBD"
            Else
                .Cells(y, 7) = "No HBD"
            End If
        Next y
    End With

End Sub
```

NB: `Cells(Row, Column)` is used in place of `Range` - easier for referencing a single cell using row/column numbers.